# How to set two different size's of background images for activity as horizontal and vertical in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set two different size's of background images for activity as horizontal and vertical.how do it,because same image set for both horizontal and vertical they get stretch.

For example:

[image: Example of horizontal and vertical layouts]

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you, make it understandable,, or give example

Comment: i thing create two layout file one is portrait and land mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please go through the below developer link that let you know about the folder structure of images to support landscape and portrait layouts..

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

The basic to differentiate the image for landscape and portrait is to put portrait image into **drawable** folder and landscape image into **drawable-land** folder.. but different size needs some more specifications that will you know more from the above developer link..

Hope it will help you..!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
    main.xml   

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ln_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ln_vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        </RelativeLayout>




    main.java

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final LinearLayout ln_hori;
        final LinearLayout ln_ver;
        Button b;
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ln_hori=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln_horizontal);
        ln_ver=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln_vertical);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ln_hori.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    ln_hori.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ln_ver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else
                {
                    ln_hori.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ln_ver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello Daxesh i need your help

Comment: chalne bhai kal no msg aje jove 6e ato free 6u to msg karyo to

Comment: bol bhai kevu chale 6e.

Comment: Kemnu 6e bhai ? Ae Bhale Bhale Bapu

Answer (score 2):

Create a **layout-land** directory inside res folder and put the landscape version of your layout XML file in that directory.

For example you use main.xml layout then you have to put main.xml file for both orientation.

Like this

For potrait :

> res/layout/
>
> ```
>        main.xml
> ```

And for Landscape mode :

> ```
>  res/layout-land/
>
>        main.xml
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As in Drawable there are already folders like **drawable-hdpi**, it supports by default  for portrait mode, You have to create folder for landscape mode like **drawable-hdpi-land** and add images in it.
**size of images for portrait mode:**

320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

**Size of images for landscape mode:**

Its opposite to the size of images as mentioned in portarit mode
For eg.: **size of image in portrait mode is 240x320 ldpi, It will be 320x240 in landscape mode**